How to add auc, best threshold, sensitivity, and specificity to grouped data
I want to take a dataset that has truth and various predictors in it and summarise the auc, 'best' threshold, sensitivity, and specificity for each predictor, split by some grouping variable.
Example that works for one predictor variable ("mpg") :
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>% 
  group_modify(~ data.frame(auc = as.numeric(pROC::auc(pROC::roc(.,response="vs", predictor="mpg"))))) %>%
  left_join(
    mtcars %>%
      group_by(am) %>% 
      group_modify(~ pROC::coords(pROC::roc(.,response="vs", predictor="mpg"),"best")), 
  by="am")

Producing this:
# A tibble: 2 × 5
# Groups:   am [2]
     am   auc threshold specificity sensitivity
  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1     0 0.946      17.6       0.833           1
2     1 0.952      21.2       0.833           1

This is a little ugly and inefficient.  Is there a less clunky way to get the same output, and also iterate over multiple predictors?  Probably using map()?
I realize that I can just put the above into a function like:
myfun = function(v1, v2) { 
  mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>% 
  group_modify(~ data.frame(auc = as.numeric(pROC::auc(pROC::roc_(.,response=v1, predictor=v2))))) %>%
  left_join(
    mtcars %>%
      group_by(am) %>% 
      group_modify(~ pROC::coords(pROC::roc_(.,response=v1, predictor=v2),"best")), 
  by="am")
}

myfun("vs","mpg") %>%
  mutate(v1 = "vs", v2 = "mpg") %>%
  bind_rows(myfun("vs","cyl") %>%
              mutate(v1 = "vs", v2 = "cyl"))

but again, this feels very inefficient and clunky.
I was thinking something more like:
mtcars %>%
  group_by(am) %>%
  map(c("mpg","cyl"), .f = ~{myfun("vs",.x)})

but this doesn't work.

The line map(c("mpg","cyl"), .f = ~{myfun("vs",.x)}) should work when run on its own. The grouped dataframe is already in the function so doesn't need piped in!

interesting. and the output is a list.  is there a way to make the output a data frame or tibble instead?

A suggested way below!

For a dataframe output you can perhaps use map_df. I'd suggest modifying your function to create a new column to denote what the v2 value being assessed in that row is:
library(tidyverse)

myfun = function(v1, v2) { 
  mtcars %>%
    group_by(am) %>% 
    group_modify(~ data.frame(auc = as.numeric(pROC::auc(pROC::roc_(.,response=v1, predictor=v2))))) %>%
    left_join(
      mtcars %>%
        group_by(am) %>% 
        group_modify(~ pROC::coords(pROC::roc_(.,response=v1, predictor=v2),"best")), 
      by="am") %>%
    mutate(v2 = v2)
}

map_df(c("mpg","cyl"), .f = ~{myfun("vs",.x)})

#> # A tibble: 4 × 6
#> # Groups:   am [2]
#>      am   auc threshold specificity sensitivity v2   
#>   <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     0 0.946      17.6       0.833           1 mpg  
#> 2     1 0.952      21.2       0.833           1 mpg  
#> 3     0 1           7         1               1 cyl  
#> 4     1 0.917       5         0.833           1 cyl

